# How To Hide the Create Issue button from JIRA top bar

Tags: hide, jira

I need help to How To Hide the Create Issue button from JIRA top bar
Please help me in this regard

Reg
Nitesh

Answer (score 0):

Start with the docs at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Project+Permissions and set the Create Issue permission